# Deserializing numerical fields with JSON and Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, deserialization, resttemplate

I'm calling a WS using Spring and Resttemplate, and trying to parse the JSON response to a custom object.

**WS call snippet:**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String wsURL = "https://www.dummyws.com";
String accessToken = "dummyAccessToken"

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
headers.add("Accept", "*/*");

MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();                       
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> wsRequest = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<GetPassengersData> wsResponse = restTemplate.exchange(wsURL, HttpMethod.GET, wsRequest, GetPassengersData.class);
GetPassengersData getPassengerData = wsResponse.getBody();
```

**WS response snippet:**

```
{
"data" : [{
        "start" : "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
        "finish" : "2018-01-01 23:59:59",
        "total" : 1076
    }
]
```

}

**Custom object definition:**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class GetPassengersData implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GetPassengersData() 
    {   
    }       

    private List<GetPassengersDataItem> data;
    public List<GetPassengersDataItem> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<GetPassengersDataItem> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
public static class GetPassengersDataItem implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GetPassengersDataItem() 
    {   
    }       

    private String start;
    private String finish;
    private double total;

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
    public String getFinish() {
        return finish;
    }
    public void setFinish(String finish) {
        this.finish = finish;
    }
    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception in `restTemplate.exchange`:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@552b744a; line: 5, column: 44] (through reference chain: *.GetPassengersData["data"]->*.GetPassengersDataItem["total"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
```

Parsing just String fields works nicely. What I'm missing? What do I need to do to parse a numerical field? I've tried with int, long, double, BigDecimal, getting the same exception error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try WS response without "data" node

```
{ 
  [{
    "start" : "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    "finish" : "2018-01-01 23:59:59",
    "total" : 1076
  }]
}
```

Or try to mappe to an object with a property `List<GetPassengersData> data`

Comment: I think that's not the issue since it works nicely if I avoid "total" field. "start" and "finish" are mapped in GetPassengersDataItem and GetPassengersData objects. 
The problem is just the numerical field in the JSON response.

Comment: try with 2 items of GetPassengersDataItem without total to test. Maybe avoid the "Get" in your class naming.